# No permissions to read notes

Tags: wordpress, api, evernote

My API key is tanggaowei-3983, but it has not permissions to read notes! This is too bad.

Can you help me，please?

please see the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your key is Basic access, it doesn't have a permission to read notes. Read this link and create a full access key or ask dev support to update the existing key.
http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/permissions.php